# Use iTerm2 and Mac OSX 10.8.3 to open tabbed shells to specific systems

Tags: macos, mac, bash, ssh, iterm2

I'm still fairly new to the MAC and I have been seeking a way to script or use the GUI to accomplish the following.

Open Iterm to a group of hosts and ssh to each of them in a tabbed view.

In the gui I can do

New Window -->> Profiles -->> open Profile I created

This gives me a single window that will execute an ssh command to a single host.

Any help or direction greatly appreciated.

I have read through the similar questions before posting as none of them seemed to solve my issue.

Comment: Which posts exactly did you read, what did you try?

Comment: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070711123202297  This is the first hit I have found that seems to match what I am hoping to accomplish.  Prior to this I had read several threads related to iterm/ssh iterm/applescript etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uh-huh. If I got things right, you can do that just right with the [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/downloads).

First, create the needed profiles in `Preferences - Profiles`. You can use a "Send text at start" box to send whatever command you need when you open that profile. For example, let's use `ssh root@192.168.1.1`:

[image: iTerm2 Preferences - Profiles]

Second, you have to create a desired arrangement. For that, just create the tabs or splits you need with the needed profile. You can add new tabs with `Profiles - Open` (Cmd+O) in the menubar. Just select the profile and press the button (New Tab / Split):

[image: Profiles - Open...]

You also can change profile of the existing tabs/splits by right-clicking the content of that terminal and choosing `Edit Session...`.

When you have the desired window/tab/split layout, save it via `Window - Save Window Arrangement`.

And now, you finally can use Window - Restore Window Arrangement to load everything automatically.

iTerm2 is a very powerful tool, you can tweak it for your needs, assign some hotkeys to make actions faster and whatever.

Comment: thank you for this trick !!!